# Submit a form from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble implementing a functionality on my c#/asp.net app.

I have a form with a RadioButtonList and a submit button. 
The RadioButtonList is generated on `Page_Load()` from a list of objects I retrieve from the database.
I would like to automatically submit the form if there is only 1 object in the list.

I have access to my Form object, to the submit button etc... but I can't seem to find a solution (in the end I'm looking for a kind of `form.Submit()` ) method.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could do this ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT >> Here is the code :

.aspx : http://pastebin.com/0E6T7dqH

.aspx.cs : http://pastebin.com/54payZJP

EDIT2 >>>

As it seems there is no way to do what I wanted to do at first, I ended up using a session variable with a response.redirect()

Source :
http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/11/26/ways-to-pass-data-between-webforms.aspx

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I've tried to find a method that submits a given form, doesn't seem to exist.
Then I've tried to see if I could simulate a button.click, doesn't seem to exist either.

I also tried doing a response.write(<script>...</script>) to submit the form with javascript, maybe it's possible but it's not a very "pretty" solution. In the end the only way seems to be sending directly my post data to the page the form leads to, but I feel like killing an ant with a bazooka (and sending POST data to another page seems to be a pain in the *ss as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to do something similar, once. Here is a way you can do it.

Asp.Net buttons have a property called `PostBackUrl`, and it does exactly what you would expect - it controls where the form will post if you click the button.

You can also use the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) function to render javascript on the page.

Now, with these two pieces, you can achieve your goal.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    if(results == 1)
    {
        button.PostBackUrl = "next page's url"
        //Register script to click the button using RegisterStartupScript
    }
}
```

Now, having shown you this, I will warn you it may not make for the best user experience. When I did it, it was for a very specific case that had no other solution. The page will actually post back to the user, and they will see the page for a moment before the javascript to click the button takes effect. Additionally, when you set a button's PostBackUrl, that means that when it is clicked, your entire form will be posted to the page specified. The code behind for the current page will not fire at all, so if you have any validation, it won't run.

There's nothing wrong with letting the user click the button to submit the form even if they only have one choice. In my experience, users like to feel like they are in control on the system; they don't like it when pages just do things without their input.

Also, there is not really anything wrong with putting the information the next page needs into the session or even a database table, and using `Response.Redirect`. It's a fairly common practice and works reliably in most scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I already used the PostBackUrl for the button (take a look at my .aspx file, I put it directly there).

I arrived to the same conclusion as you did : execute some JS code is possible, but maybe not the best practice.
So in the end I did like you advised and used a Session Variable, then Response.Redirect and I destroy the variable right after that.

Answer (score 3):

Post happens in the client side. As in Page_Load you are currently executing in the server side, just call the code you want to execute on post.

**Edit: For actually going to another aspx**

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(!IsPostback && OnlyOneItem) {
        Server.Transfer("TheOtherPage.aspx");
    }
}
```

Server.Transfer will maintain the entire request, so your post data will be available.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx

Comment: The form leads to another page on which I retrieve the post data.
So the only solution for me would be to send the post data manually from codebehind to the other page ?

Comment: You could use Server.Transfer or, worst case, Response.Redirect

Comment: Yeah, but I need to get my POST data, which I'm not sure is possible to transmit with theses methods

Comment: You don't understand the way that a ASP.NET page work. If you in code-behind, you ALREADY got your data. You just need to send it to your next page. If you need more specific help, please show us all the codes (Your 2 pages code-front and code-behind).

Comment: I know I already got my data, but in order to send it to the next page I'm going to need to create my own POST request etc..., and it seems very complicated given that I just need one form to be submitted / one button to be clicked to do the exact same thing...

Then again, it's very likely I don't understand some specific ASP.net stuff since I'm new to it (I usually use Java).

Anyway, I still don't really know what to do so I've added the code in the question. Thanks again !

Comment: using Server.Transfer transfers the entire request, so you will have your post data. Anyway, this is not the way asp.net webforms is supposed to be used.

Comment: So what would you recommend doing ?

Comment: I'll post the idea in the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

In your `Page_Load`

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
      if(check for only one object)
      {
         //your submit code
      }
}
```