# How to submit a form programmatically from code behind to an external site

Tags: asp.net, forms, code-behind

I try to get values of a programmatically created `HtmlForm` to an external site. This site requires the data to be sent as `POST`, as it may contain sensible information.

I generate the `HtmlForm` from a JSon-Response like this:

```
JObject jsonResponseActionData = (JObject)joResponse["action_data"];
var redirectURL = (JValue)jsonResponseActionData["url"];

HtmlForm form= new HtmlForm {
    Method = "post",
    Action = redirectURL.ToString()
};

var inputTypeString = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"inputName\" value=\"inputValue\">";
foreach (var obj in jsonResponseFields) {
    if (obj.Value.ToString() == "") {
        form.InnerHtml += inputTypeString.Replace("inputName", obj.Key).Replace("inputValue", "").Replace(">", " disabled >");
    } else {
        form.InnerHtml += inputTypeString.Replace("inputName", obj.Key).Replace("inputValue", obj.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

If I write it like this into an HTML-File and add a submit button to it, I can submit this to the external site successfully, so I am able to take the JSon-Response and extract all the information from there correctly.

What I have tried:

- Adding a hidden form element to the apsx-page, but [this isn't possible and results in an empty stack error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374283/empty-stack-error-when-adding-form-tag-to-an-asp-net-webforms-page)
- [submitting it with `Server.Transfer` and `Response.Redirect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010941/submit-a-form-from-code-behind), but both throw exceptions (`System.ArgumentException` and `ThreadAbortException`, respectively), since I want to reach an external site

How can I submit my generated form to the external site? Note that this site does indeed require me to submit a form, so any other solution not involving the submitting of a form are not constructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now implemented a workaround, maybe this is helpful to others (but maybe this answer is downvoted into oblivion because it is such an awful hack?):

I create a new HTML page in a subfolder. This subfolder is protected by `Web.config` and `.htaccess` (because I didn't find a way to disallow calling *.html-files in `Web.config`), meaning the files cannot be listed from an external source and the files cannot be viewed either, even if you know the file name.

This HTML page contains nothing but the form I want to submit and a bit of JavaScript which automatically clicks the submit button on page load:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function clickButton(){
            document.getElementById("submitForm").click();
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="clickButton()">
    <!--Actual content goes here-->
</body>
```

I then redirect the user to that page with:

```
Response.Redirect(pageName);
```

once the handling of the JSON data is done.

This will work in my case because the user is redirected to the external site anyway, in the best case s/he won't even notice the redirect to this intermediate site, and even if it is noticed, the page doesn't contain anything the user doesn't already know, plus the data in the HTML file isn't sensitive, this data has to be entered by the user on the external site, so there's no possible security breach here. At least none I can think of right now.